# At time to result

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My code:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:mm:ss.fff}")]
public DateTime? Time { get; set; }
```

Question:

When I try to at a time, I have to add "0:" before the time.. Does someone know how to enter without the "0:"?

(I need it to enter an athletics time.)

Comment: What do you mean by "at" a time? "At" isn't the word you're after there.

Comment: Maybe he means "add"? Can you expand a bit more on what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried? I am assuming here that you want to be able to not enter "0:" in the UI for the `Time` field?

Comment: your quest is confusing. if you want to replace the 0, do you mean you want to add hours part of time?

Comment: indeed, at should be add, sorry

Comment: Consider my time is 1min, 17sec and 123 thousands. everything works if I type 0:01:17.123, but not if I type 01:17.123..

Comment: @user2323240 Alternatively, if this is a UI problem, you can capture the time in a string using a `mm:ss.ffff` regex and buffer the hours when storing in database.

Comment: If you mean 'add' and not 'at' then perhaps you can edit your question to say 'add' and not 'at'.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the annotations yo uadded to the `Time` field:

```
DataFormatString = "{0:mm:ss.fff}"
```

This won't match up with:

```
0:mm:ss.fff
01:17.123
```

but it does with

```
 0:01:17.123
 0:mm:ss.fff
```

Hence why `0:01:17.123` works yet `01:17.123` doesn't

Comment: I think you missed his point. OP wants to know how to remove the hours portion because it's not relevant. The answer is, OP cannot. Time inherently includes hours, and that, sadly is the answer.

Comment: @user2323240 Alternatively, if this is a UI problem, you can capture the time in a string using a mm:ss.ffff regex and buffer the hours when storing in database.